# XcodeでGitのCommitが反映されなくなった

Tags: xcode, git

Xcodeでローカルリポジトリだけを使いGitを利用しています。
ある日を境にあるプロジェクトだけ、Commitの結果が履歴に追加表示されなくなりました。

以下を試しましたが、変わりません。
・Xcodeを15.2から15.3にバージョンアップ
・Integrate - Refresh File Status 実行
・Product - Clean Build Folder 実行

どなたか原因を教えていただけませんでしょうか。